# Building android application on top of a ussd application

Tags: java

Is there a way of sending and receiving ussd request on an android using java? I am trying to build an android app that communicates with a ussd app. Is there a way I can do that in java?

Comment: what have you tried? The question is too broad as it is

Comment: I have tried to search through the Internet to find a way I can do it.. I haven't found any useful links.